# Retrieving response of POST (with custom header in HTML) request and use it as variable in front-end page

Tags: html, post, authorization, token, response

I need to write a web-page in which I embed a chart.

The page I wrote is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function makeFrame() {
ChartToken = "XXXXXXX";
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://url.com/charts/"+ ChartToken +"#/embedded");
ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="#" onMouseDown="makeFrame()">GO! </a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I manually set ChartToken with the correct string this is working. However, the value of ChartToken should be retrieved via a POST request.

I have been told that the POST request should go in the back-end server. However, I don't even know how to write in the back-end server and how to write the POST request. Also, I'm not sure if I really need to write in the back-end or I could simply make the POST request in the front-end page above.

At the moment, in order to obtain the ChartToken I use Advanced REST client. I fill in the Advanced REST client fields the values for the url:

```
https://url.com/1/embeddedCharts
```

for the RAW headers:

```
Authorization: Token YYYYYYYY
Content-Type: application/json
```

and for the RAW payload:

```
{"apiToken": "YYYYYYYY",
"chartId": "ZZZZZZZ"}
```

(notice that the Athorization: Token and the apiToken are the same) and I receive as response:

```
{
"token": "KKKKKKK"
}
```

This is the value that I put in the ChartToken in order to be able to embed the chart. However, this value can only be used once and at each page load I need to obtain a new token to put in ChartToken.

Therefore I wrote a page to retrieve the token (that I wanted to use to send the value of the token to ChartToken):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title Goes Here</title>
</head>
<body>   
<p>This is my web page</p>
<form action="https://url.com/1/embeddedCharts" method="post" enctype="application/json">
<input name="apiToken" value="YYYYYYYY">
<input name="chartId" value="ZZZZZZZ">
<button>Send my data</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this page doesn't work. Maybe because I don't send the RAW header:

```
Authorization: Token YYYYYYYY
```

as I do in the Advanced REST client? I have read in some other forum that this is not possible in html, because I cannot define a custom header. Is this true?

Or maybe because

```
enctype="application/json"
```

doesn't actually replace

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

that I use the Advance REST client?

Or maybe because I don't write this page in the back-end server? How would I do that?

So, the solution to my problem would be to know:

1) How to write the POST request to obtain the token for the chart.

2) Where to write the request, if in the back-end.

3) How to pass the value to my front-end page, essentially to ChartToken.

Please, consider that I can only write a bit of html for front-end pages and I don't know much about web architectures. The easiest for me would be to have a full example with all the indications.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not use [AJAX](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/) to make your request instead of an HTML form?

Comment: I don't know how to write in AJAX. As I said, I only know a bit of html for front-end pages.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make the POST request from a jquery script within the html front-end page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var reportId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX", // Required
               apiToken = "YYYYYYYYYY", // Required

                containerId = "embeddedReport", // Required

                documentId = "", // Optional
                dateRange = {"mode": "LAST_7_DAYS"}, // Optional
                slicer = {
                        
    }, // Optional

                // Report size
                width = 1000,
                height = 400,

                // leave that variable NULL
                ReportToken = null;

            

            function getReportTokenJS(apiToken, reportId, width, height, containerId) {
                var payLoadData = createPayLoadData();

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) {

                    }
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        ReportToken = data.token;
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.style.width = width + 'px';
                        iframe.style.height = height + 'px';
                        iframe.src = 'https://app.somepage.com/reports/' + ReportToken;
                        document.getElementById(containerId).appendChild(iframe);
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://app.somepage.com/1/embeddedReports", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payLoadData));


            };

            function createPayLoadData() {
                if (apiToken == "" || apiToken == null || reportId == "" || reportId == null) {
                    console.log("ERROR: apiToken Or reportId is missing");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var payLoadData = {};
                    payLoadData.apiToken = apiToken;
                    payLoadData.reportId = reportId;
                }

                if (documentId != "" && documentId != null) {
                    payLoadData.documentId = documentId;
                }

                if (Object.keys(dateRange).length > 0) {
                    payLoadData.dateRange = dateRange;
                }

                if (Object.keys(slicer).length > 0) {
                    payLoadData.slicer = slicer;
                }

                return payLoadData;
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

  <button type="button" onclick="getReportTokenJS(apiToken, reportId, width, height, containerId);">generate embedded report</button>
        <div id="embeddedReport"></div>

    

    </body>
 
</html>
```

Now, I would need to know how to pass values for reportId and apiToken to the jquery script variables. Please, consider that I found this example somewhere, so I don't really know how to program in jquery. A full working example modifying the code I provide here would be to only way to show me how to do.